# aws transcribe for .net example cannot be found

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

Hello I am trying to find how to write a aws transcribe app using the API for dotnet, but there is no documentation on it, except for a python example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/getting-started-python.html

anyone know to write this for .net?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the .NET SDK API reference. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html

Here's the service you are interested in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/TranscribeService/NTranscribeService.html

For example, here's a method that in your python example is "start_transcription_job", here it's basically the same.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/TranscribeService/MTranscribeServiceStartTranscriptionJobStartTranscriptionJobRequest.html

In general the API's will be similar and the python example should be enough.

If you have more concrete questions when trying to implement .NET SDK, you can ask again.